# Why are the two randomly generated arrays always the same?

Tags: ruby, random

I'm trying to generate two arrays with random content. The code is as follows:

```
[@board1, @board2].each do |board|
  15.times { board.place_random_ship }
end
```

Within `Board` class, I have these two methods:

```
def place_random_ship
  self.full? ? (raise puts "error") : self.populate_grid
end

def populate_grid
  position = [rand(@grid.length), rand(@grid.length)]
  self.empty?(position) ? self[position] = :s : self.populate_grid
end
```

I made sure the boards I pass are different:

```
#<Board:0x007fc8e58641f0>
#<Board:0x007fc8e58641a0>
```

Each time I run my code, the contents change, but the two arrays are always the same, and I want them to be different. I tried putting `srand` at the beginning of my `populate_grid` method, but that didn't do anything. How do I get my arrays to have different content?

The class definition and some possibly relevant methods are as follows:

```
class Board
  attr_accessor :grid, :default_grid

  @default_grid = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) }

  def initialize(grid = self.class.default_grid)
    @grid = grid
  end

  def self.default_grid
    Board.new(@default_grid)
    @default_grid
  end

  def [](position)
    @grid[position[1]][position[0]]
  end

  def []=(position, arg)
    @grid[position[1]][position[0]] = arg
  end
```

Some of the class methods are there from an older, dumbed down version I had to make to pass a spec file. I load those files and run this ruby code to "play" the game:

```
players = { player1: ComputerPlayer.new("rafi"), player2: ComputerPlayer.new("other") }
boards = { board1: Board.new, board2: Board.new }
game = BattleshipGame.new(players, boards)
game.play
```

And this is what a grid looks like (empty 10x10):

```
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

This is what the grid looks like after I run that 15.times code:

```
[:s, :s, nil, :s, nil, :s, nil, nil, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, :s, nil]
[nil, nil, :s, nil, nil, nil, :s, :s, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, :s, nil, nil, nil]
[:s, nil, :s, nil, nil, :s, nil, :s, :s, nil]
[nil, nil, :s, nil, nil, nil, nil, :s, nil, :s]
[:s, nil, nil, nil, nil, :s, :s, nil, :s, nil]
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, :s]
[nil, :s, nil, nil, :s, nil, :s, :s, nil, nil]
[nil, nil, :s, nil, :s, :s, nil, nil, :s, nil]
```

And the problem is, both boards, which ought to have different ship placements since the code uses `rand`, somehow end up having the exact same ship placement.

Comment: why not show us the contents of the arrays?  Right now you're just showing us the object and not it's contents.

Comment: Also, not showing which variable is being populated and how. Could you show code for `Board#[]` - assuming I am reading this correctly you have `def [] array` somewhere and this is what is called on the last line of `populate_grid`

Comment: `...generate two arrays...`  - where are two arrays?  All I see is an array with 2 elements in `populate_grid`

Comment: And what is `Board` class?

Comment: What is `full?`? What is `@grid`?

Comment: @fl00r: I've added a link to the full version of all the class methods. You can see them here: https://gist.github.com/RowiDont/2f39724681c4433962ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where things start to go wrong:

```
  @default_grid = Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) }

  def initialize(grid = self.class.default_grid)
```

The problem is that you *re-use* the `@default_grid` object, so all your instances of Board that are instantiated with the default will share the same `Array`.

Instead of using a class variable, you should modify the `default_grid` method to generate a new `Array` each time:

```
  def self.default_grid
    Array.new(10) { Array.new(10) }
  end
```

You can get rid of the class variable.

Comment: Thank you! This is a really good lesson for me, as I struggled previously to realize what exactly class and instance variables were. Is there a way I could have found this out with debugging that you could suggest?

Comment: @rPat: Comparing `boards[:board1].grid.object_id` and `boards[:board1].grid.object_id` would have shown you had shared the grid between your two `Board` objects.